# How to display database value inside select tag using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help .I can not display some db values inside select tag using PHP and MySQL.I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($row['status']==1){
         $status=1;
     }else{
     $status=0; 
    }
    $id=$row['id'];
    echo "<tr>
     <td>".$counter++."</td>
     <td>".$row['pincode']."</td>
    <td>".$row['area']."</td>
    <td>
    <select class='form-control' id='status' name='status' onchange='javascript:adminstatus()' style='height:23px; padding:0px;'>
         <option value=''>Select Status</option>
        <option value='1'  ".$row['status']."=='1'?'selected':'';>Enable</option>
     <option value='0'  ".$row['status']."=='0'?'selected':'';>Disable</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    ?>
```

Here I need when `$status==1` the enable will select and `$status==0` disable will select.Please help me.

Comment: Are you only selecting one row? The ternary operator is currently part of the string.

Comment: yes,here when the status is 1 the enable will selected otherwise disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** UPDATE **
Correction I would take your  statements out of an echo and just use the echo for the php values. It will be easier to read and maintain. For example:

```
<td><?php echo $counter++ ?></td>
```

Then I would write the logic part like so

```
<option value='1' <?php echo ($row['status']=='1'? 'selected' : '') ?>>Enable</option>
<option value='0' <?php echo ($row['status']=='0'? 'selected' : '') ?>>Disable</option>
```

However, if you want to write the code the way you have...

```
$id=$row['id'];
echo "<tr>
 <td>".$counter++."</td>
 <td>".$row['pincode']."</td>
<td>".$row['area']."</td>
<td>
<select class='form-control' id='status' name='status' onchange='javascript:adminstatus()' style='height:23px; padding:0px;'>
     <option value=''>Select Status</option>
    <option value='1' " . ($row['status']=='1'?'selected':'') . ">Enable</option>
 <option value='0' " . ($row['status']=='0'?'selected':'') . ">Disable</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Comment: You're welcome. As chris85 mentioned, you should switch your `mysql_` statements to `mysqli` (or `PDO`) as `mysql` is depreciated and future support for it is not guaranteed. It will also be more secure.